# Localization Microsoft Word citation and bibliography styles (xsl file)

Tags: xslt, ms-word, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, bibliography

i want to Create a Custom bibliography styles in MSWORD 2013 ,I use [this style](http://bibword.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Home) .
I use the IEEE_Reference.XSL and I've applied the changes desired  . and it's ok.

But my article has multiple language references .I want Localization my  bibliography styles as Microsoft word default bibliography styles do.

I know it that i should use LCID for this,

some part of my code is like this:

```
<source type="Book">
<column id="1">
<halign>right</halign>
<valign>top</valign>
<format>{[%RefOrder%]}</format>
</column>
<column id="2">
<halign>left</halign>
<valign>top</valign>

 <format >{%Author:1|Editor:2%, }{&lt;i&gt;%Title%&lt;/i&gt;{, %Edition:o% ed.}}{, %Editor:2%}.{ %City|StateProvince|CountryRegion%}{, %StateProvince|CountryRegion%}{, %CountryRegion%}{: %Publisher%}{,{ %Month:s%} %Year%}{, vol. %Volume%}{, %Comments%}.{ [Online]. %URL:l%}</format>

</column>
<sortkey></sortkey>
</source>
```

My goal is code like this:

```
xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="b:LCID='1033'">
--ENGILSH FORMAT
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
--PERSIAN FORMAT
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

but it does not work and always choose xsl:otherwise .

anybody can help me to do this Condition?
thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the IEEE_Reference.xsl - in my Office 15 Lcid is used via `b:StyleNameLocalized/b:Lcid`